# Spring Security Authentication Provider autenticate()'s reason for returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Lately, I was studying Spring security's Authentication provider.

In the authenticate() method the docs say, "***May return null if the AuthenticationProvider is unable to support authentication of the passed Authentication object. In such a case, the next AuthenticationProvider that supports the presented Authentication class will be tried.***"

We have another method **supports()** that indicates that if this provider supports the type of authentication or not.

As far as I know **"AuthenticationManager"** first calls ***supports()*** to check if the provider supports this type or not. Then the **authenticate()** method is called. So, from my understanding authenticate is only called when the provider supports it.

***So, My question is " If the provider supports this type of auth, then why should it return null from authenticating ()? and why do the docs say *"May return null if the AuthenticationProvider is unable to support authentication of the passed Authentication object"* ??? Should it not always support it? (Because we checked its compatibility via supports().)***

Can you give an example where the provider needs to return null?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quote from [Spring Security in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617297739) by Laurentiu Spilca

> The second method in the AuthenticationProvider interface is supports-
> (Class<?> authentication). You can implement this method to return
> true if the current AuthenticationProvider supports the type provided
> as an Authentication object. Observe that even if this method returns
> true for an object, there is still a chance that the authenticate()
> method rejects the request by returning null. Spring Security is
> designed like this to be more flexible and to allow you to implement
> an AuthenticationProvider that can reject an authentication request
> based on the request’s details, not only by its type.

and its analogy I think clear things up.

> An analogy of how the authentication manager and authentication
> provider work together to validate or invalidate an authentication
> request is having a more complex lock for your door. You can open this
> lock either by using a card or an old fashioned physical key
> . The lock itself is the authentication manager that decides whether to open the door. To make that decision, it delegates to the
> two authentication providers: one that knows how to validate the card
> or the other that knows how to verify the physical key. If you present
> a card to open the door, the authentication provider that works only with physical keys complains that it doesn’t know this kind of authentication.
> But the other provider supports this kind of authentication and verifies whether the
> card is valid for the door. This is actually the purpose of the supports() methods.
> Besides testing the authentication type, Spring Security adds one more layer for
> flexibility. The door’s lock can recognize multiple kinds of cards. In this case, when
> you present a card, one of the authentication providers could say, “I understand this
> as being a card. But it isn’t the type of card I can validate!” This happens when supports() returns true but authenticate() returns null.

[image]